# How to make man pages?

Tags: scripts, make, manpage

I know how to make commands(scripts) in Linux.

I would like to know if I could make man pages for the commands?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! *Before create a new question, you should see if this has not been created previously.* This will be closed as a duplicate soon. But have in mind that for the next time.. Take a look at the duplicated post: [How to create a manpage?](http://askubuntu.com/q/42923/62483)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Google is your friend

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-creating-a-manpage/

This lays out in detail what is required. You will need to use sudo to create the pages. Use the built in editor like vim

Comment: Google is the reason people come here. Lets not lose viewers and be a simple redirect site.