# How to disable updating man page even I update/upgrade the package itself

Tags: software-recommendation, manpage

For personal use I want to edit some man pages in my system, including adding some notes and removing many unneeded lines.

So my question is how to establish that?

Back to my question [What is the default PAGER used by man pages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623992/what-is-the-default-pager-used-by-man-pages) I've learnt how to change the default man PAGER.

For example I'm gonna use `gedit`. This could be done by

```
man -P gedit some-man-page
```

and then I do edits and then save as new file then by help of [How to create a manpage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42923/how-to-create-a-manpage) I could create a new man page of that command.

But, this would put me in  problem of presence of two man pages of same command.

So, in other words what is the best application (GUI is preferred) to edit `man pages`

UPDATE:

I found that I could make the edit using the `gmanedit`. to install use :

```
sudo apt-get install gmanedit
```

But the question is how to make this modification persistent after a package update/upgrade. I'e How to disable updating man page even I update/upgrade the package itself.

Comment: You can use any application you wish, gedit or  Gmanedit. You will have to run it as root. Be warned, it is likely your edits will be over written when you upgrade a packages. Probably better to save your edited man pages in /usr/local

Comment: In gedit I can't save it even I'm running as root Else it offers an option `save as` so I can't save to the same file itself.

Comment: @Maythux If the file is readonly, some applications will not allow root to write to it. You have to set it to writable, and then write to it; some editors will automatically do this for you. [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) does it, but it has a learning curve.

Comment: You're essentially asking two questions here. May want to clean that up.