# Create manual for program installed from source

Tags: software-installation, manpage

Generally, when I install a package from the source, I can't use the `man` command to see the manual of that package. I guess because there is no manual installed with it.

So, is there a way to install a manual for a package installed from the source ??!!

PS : I know that using the option `--help` with almost every program will bring me some kind of help, or even a manual of the command, but I really need to install a real manual, the one that can be brought with the `man` command.

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: See [How to create a manpage?](http://askubuntu.com/q/42923)

Comment: @JonasCz The link you gave explains for the developers how to create their manpages (I guess). I am looking how to install manpages of an open source program that isn't mine.

Comment: It's going to depend on the particular package i.e. whether it includes manual pages, and whether the default install command processes and installs them (for example, some provide a separate Makefile target such as `make docs` that you can use)

Comment: Can I have an example please, of any open source package (It will be better if you can give me an example with metasploit, but I guess that I am asking a lot this way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man man` says:

```
   -l, --local-file
          Activate `local' mode.  Format and display  local  manual  files
```

You can use `man --local-file /path/to/file`. For example, if you want to read a man page called `example`, you can use `man --local-file ./example`, assuming such file exists in the current directory.

Comment: Here is the complete problem : I use the `fish` shell, and this shell parse the manpages looking for parameters (for autocompletion). So I need to generate and install manpages to help `fish` parse the parameters of the programs that I install from the source.

Comment: @Sidahmed Have you tried moving the man page file to `/usr/local/man/man1` with `sudo mv example /usr/local/man/man1` ? Then close the shell and try `man example`.

Comment: I don't know where to find the manpages of the open source program, I don't have a lot of informations about this subject.

Comment: @Sidahmed does the project have man pages?

Comment: Is it the folder doc-pak ??!!

Comment: @Sidahmed I don't know. Could you please send me a direct link to the project?

Comment: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42011/discussion-between-grooveplex-and-sidahmed).

Comment: https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=174 :)